# AngularJS -- Custom Directive Won't Work Properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to AngularJS here. After struggling for >= 3 hours, I can't seem to get my custom directive working, even though I fully grasp what I'm trying to do, and generally understand how creating and including a custom directive in an HTML file is supposed to happen.

MY QUESTION: How can I get the expression in the custom directive to successfully appear on the page?

The files are below. Assistance would be immensely appreciated! Thanks in advance.

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="favoritePlayers">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <title>My Favorite Players</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Expression within controller -->
    <section ng-controller="NFLController as nfl">
        <h1>why does this work?</h1>
        <div ng-repeat="team in nfl.teams">
            <h3> {{team.qb}}</h3>
        </div>
    </section>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- Using a custom directive instead -->
    <section ng-controller="NFLController as nfl">
        <h1>...but this doesn't?</h1>
        <div ng-repeat="team in nfl.teams">
            <running-backs></running-backs>
        </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
(function(){

var app = angular.module("favoritePlayers", []);

app.controller("NFLController", function(){
    this.teams = league;
});

app.directive('runningBacks', function(){
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'running-backs.html',
        //controller:
        //controllerAs: 
    };
});

var league = [
    {
        teamName: "Philadelphia Eagles",
        qb: "Mark Sanchez",
        rb: "LeSean McCoy",
        wr: "Jeremy Maclin",
        superbowl_contender: true
    },
    {
        teamName: "Dallas Cowboys",
        qb: "Tony Romo",
        rb: "Demarco Murray",
        wr: "Dez Bryant",
        superbowl_contender: true
    },
    {
        teamName: "New York Giants",
        qb: "Eli Manning",
        rb: "Rashad Jennings",
        wr: "Odell Beckham Jr.",
        superbowl_contender: false
    },      
    {
        teamName: "Washington Redskins",
        qb: "Robert Griffin III",
        rb: "Alfred Morris",
        wr: "Desean Jackson",
        superbowl_contender: false
    },
];
})();
```

**running-backs.html**

`<h3> yo {{team.rb}} </h3>`

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: What are the contents of "running-backs.html"?

Comment: Is it finding running-backs.html correctly?  Meaning, is that templateUrl correct?  Check the console to see if there's any 404 on that file.  If I plug your markup directly into the directive and use template instead of templateUrl, it works fine.

Comment: Perhaps you need to [create  an isolate scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)....

Answer (score 0):

I think your code does work, when I tried it it seemed that the `running-backs.html` wasn't loading - were you running from a webserver or your local file system? If I use `<script type="text/ng-template" id="running-backs.html">` rather than loading from an external file, then it runs as I'd expect.

```js
(function(){

var app = angular.module("favoritePlayers", []);

app.controller("NFLController", function(){
    this.teams = league;
});

app.directive('runningBacks', function(){
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'running-backs.html',
        //controller:
        //controllerAs: 
    };
});

var league = [
    {
        teamName: "Philadelphia Eagles",
        qb: "Mark Sanchez",
        rb: "LeSean McCoy",
        wr: "Jeremy Maclin",
        superbowl_contender: true
    },
    {
        teamName: "Dallas Cowboys",
        qb: "Tony Romo",
        rb: "Demarco Murray",
        wr: "Dez Bryant",
        superbowl_contender: true
    },
    {
        teamName: "New York Giants",
        qb: "Eli Manning",
        rb: "Rashad Jennings",
        wr: "Odell Beckham Jr.",
        superbowl_contender: false
    },      
    {
        teamName: "Washington Redskins",
        qb: "Robert Griffin III",
        rb: "Alfred Morris",
        wr: "Desean Jackson",
        superbowl_contender: false
    },
];
})();
```

```html
<html ng-app="favoritePlayers">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>My Favorite Players</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Expression within controller -->
    <section ng-controller="NFLController as nfl">
        <h1>why does this work?</h1>
        <div ng-repeat="team in nfl.teams">
            <h3> {{team.qb}}</h3>
        </div>
    </section>

    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- Using a custom directive instead -->
    <section ng-controller="NFLController as nfl">
        <h1>...but this doesn't?</h1>
        <div ng-repeat="team in nfl.teams">
            <running-backs></running-backs>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="running-backs.html">
    <h3> yo {{team.rb}} </h3>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer @JohnWhish Running it from my local system. However when I add 'yo {{team.rb}}' inside the ng-repeat, I get the same result without using the script you'd added. Trying to figure this out so I can further build out the running-backs.html template and make something useful once I get a hang of this

Comment: @jarettSims Angular pulls in the `running-backs.html` template via an XHR so you need to be running it on a webserver for it to work. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a scoping issue. The best approach is to [create an isolate scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive) within your directive:

```
app.directive('runningBacks', function(){
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'running-backs.html',
        scope: { team: '=teamName' } // sets local `team` equal to the value 
                                     // of the `team-name` attribute
    };
});
```

view:

```
    <div ng-repeat="team in nfl.teams">
        <running-backs team-name="team"></running-backs>
    </div>
```

---

Full example:

```js
var app = angular.module("favoritePlayers", []);

app.controller("NFLController", function() {
  this.teams = league;
});

app.directive('runningBacks', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'running-backs.html',
    scope: {
      team: '=teamName'
    }
  };
});

var league = [{
  teamName: "Philadelphia Eagles",
  qb: "Mark Sanchez",
  rb: "LeSean McCoy",
  wr: "Jeremy Maclin",
  superbowl_contender: true
}, {
  teamName: "Dallas Cowboys",
  qb: "Tony Romo",
  rb: "Demarco Murray",
  wr: "Dez Bryant",
  superbowl_contender: true
}, {
  teamName: "New York Giants",
  qb: "Eli Manning",
  rb: "Rashad Jennings",
  wr: "Odell Beckham Jr.",
  superbowl_contender: false
}, {
  teamName: "Washington Redskins",
  qb: "Robert Griffin III",
  rb: "Alfred Morris",
  wr: "Desean Jackson",
  superbowl_contender: false
}, ];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="favoritePlayers">
  <!-- Using a custom directive instead -->
  <section ng-controller="NFLController as nfl">
    <div ng-repeat="team in nfl.teams">
      <running-backs team-name="team"></running-backs>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="running-backs.html">
    <h3> yo {{team.rb}} </h3>
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Blazemonger ... shouldn't I be able to place the text like `yo {{team.rb}}` exclusively inside the **running-backs.html** file that corresponds to the custom directive?